# Is it OK to present a sheet within a conditional subview?

Tags: animation, swiftui

My current project has a structure where a helper view (actually a couple different views) present a sheet when a button is pressed. That sheet can then actually obviate the need for the subview that presented the sheet.

To make that a little clearer, the subview is a view that alerts the user to the need to authenticate, which is done by the presented sheet. Once that is done, the view that alerted the user is removed from the main view, and I want the sheet to also go away.

It seems like the following approach works fine, but seems like it shouldn't. Is there a correct way to do this?

Here's the code:

```
class Observable:ObservableObject {
    @Published var someCondition:Bool = true
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                self.someCondition = false
            }
    }
}
struct ContentView:View {
    @StateObject var observable = Observable()
    var body:some View {
        if observable.someCondition {
           SubView()
        }
    }
}

struct SubView:View {
    @State var presenting:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.purple
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Button {
                presenting = true
            } label: {
                Text("Present")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presenting) {
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That approach is perfectly fine. I would only add that if you want your sheet to disappear, something needs to set `presenting = false`.